# Copy Value Cell worksheet to anothers first empty cell in a column, no formula copy but only displayed

Tags: excel, vba, copy, offset

At the moment I have a code that works copying and pasting the formulas of specific cells in one worksheet to another worksheets first empty cell in a column. However there is a problem regarding copying the formulas of those cells and not the displayed figures, see the following code:

```
[B3].Copy .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
[C3].Copy .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
[D3].Copy .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
[E3].Copy .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
[B5].Copy .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
[E12].Copy .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
[E24].Copy .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
```

This copies the formulas and I only want to have the **displayed value of the cell** (output). So for better explanations: Cell B3 is copied from worksheet ("Template") to the first empty cell in column B in worksheet("project_tracker")

I hope someone can help me out.

Kind regards,

Benjamin

Answer (score 1):

If you want the **value**, then do a value transfer instead of copy, something like the following:

```
Sub CopyToTracker()

    Dim templateWS As Worksheet
    Dim trackerWS As Worksheet

    Set templateWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template")
    Set trackerWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("project_tracker")

    With trackerWS
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = templateWS.Range("B3").Value
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = templateWS.Range("C3").Value
        ' and so on
    End With
End Sub
```